# Getting value from HTML select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html combo/select. When the user selects a element, I want to populate textboxcontrol from it. How to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="combobox">
     <option value="">Pick one</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input id="textbox" type="text" />
```

Javascript (assumes jQuery):

```
$('#combobox').change( function(){
     $('#textbox').val( $(this).val() );
}).click( function(){
     $('#textbox').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: I don't think IE will fire the change event until after the select loses focus, so this might not behave exactly as he is expecting for IE.

Comment: Fails when value selection changed using arrow keys in FF3.5

Comment: Yes I already have that code..but IE does not fire the change event

Comment: Edited to include click event.

Motim: If you have already tried to tackle a problem and have encountered bugs, then please mention those bugs. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html